# How to speed up pandas transform function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to speed up or vectorise the following slow code

```
    def is_outlier(s):
        lower_limit = 0
        upper_limit = s.mean() + (s.std() * 1)
        valid = s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
        s[~valid] = np.NaN
        return s

    df["Difference"] = df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform(is_outlier)
```

The intent of the code is to remove any values that are beyond the upper standard deviation and replace with NaN.

I've tried to understand the following article about vectorisation but I can't manage to apply it [How to make your Pandas operation 100x faster by
Yifei Huang](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-operation-100x-faster-81ebcd09265c)

Comment: Are you meaning to use the std dev *per customer*? This is as vectorized as you're going to get, it may just be slow because you're performing the same vectorized functions X number of times (Once per CustomerName)

Comment: Yes removing Difference values for each customer based on each customer's standard deviation and mean. Perhaps there's a way to paralellize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom function in `.transform` can be very costly because Pandas can't use the vectorized internal functions on the full dataframe. If you have a lot of groups (i.e. different customers) then this

```py
upper_limit = (
    df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform("mean")
    + df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform("std")
)
df["Difference"] = df.loc[df["Difference"].between(0, upper_limit), "Difference"]
```

would be significantly faster. (I've timed dataframes with about 1,000 - 10,000 customers and 100,000 - 1,000,000 rows.)

---

Timing setup (`test_1` is the solution in the question, `test_2` the one here):

```py
from random import seed, choice, randint
from timeit import timeit

def sample_df(num_customers, num_rows, s=123456):
    seed(s)
    customers = [*map(str, range(num_customers))]
    return pd.DataFrame(
        [[choice(customers), randint(-5, 10)] for _ in range(num_rows)],
        columns=["CustomerName", "Difference"]
    )

def is_outlier(s):
    lower_limit = 0
    upper_limit = s.mean() + s.std()
    valid = s.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)
    s[~valid] = np.NaN
    return s

def test_1(df):
    df["Difference"] = df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform(is_outlier)
    return df

def test_2(df):
    upper_limit = (
        df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform("mean")
        + df.groupby("CustomerName")["Difference"].transform("std")
    )
    df["Difference"] = df.loc[df["Difference"].between(0, upper_limit), "Difference"]
    return df

for num_customers, num_rows in (1_000, 100_000), (5_000, 100_000):
    print(f"Settings: {num_customers = }, {num_rows = }")
    for i in range(1, 3):
        df = sample_df(num_customers, num_rows)
        t = timeit(f"test_{i}(df)", globals=globals(), number=10)
        print(f"test_{i}: {t:.3f} seconds")
```

Result here:

```
Settings: num_customers = 1000, num_rows = 100000
test_1: 36.102 seconds
test_2: 0.316 seconds
Settings: num_customers = 5000, num_rows = 100000
test_1: 138.889 seconds
test_2: 0.412 seconds
```

Comment: Amazing difference thank you !